# JQuery Ajax - Code Getting Cut Off by '<'

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

New to coding and having trouble with Ajax. I'm trying to return a table of results from MySQL based on the parameters in my HTML form (this is an example for learning only, ultimate purpose will be different). The PHP/MySQL works if executed separately, but the Ajax is returning the PHP code, not the result. It seems to get cut off at a '<' in the MySQL code and return the PHP as text rather than executing it. As I mentioned I'm new so please feel free to point out anything else I can improve. Thanks!

HTML/JQuery Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <body>
        <h1> AJAX TEST </h1>
        <form id="coordinatesearch">
            <label for="maxLatInput"> Search Coordinates: <label><br>
                <input 
                    id="maxLatInput" 
                    type="decimal" 
                    placeholder="Max Latitude">
                    
                <input 
                    id="minLatInput" 
                    type="decimal" 
                    placeholder="Min Latitude">
                    
                <input 
                    id="maxLongInput" 
                    type="decimal" 
                    placeholder="Max Longitude">
                    
                <input 
                    id="minLongInput" 
                    type="decimal" 
                    placeholder="Min Longitude">
                    
                </form>
                
                <button
                    type="button"
                    onClick= filterCoordinates()> 
                    Submit
                </button>

        </form>

    </body>

    <script>
        function filterCoordinates() {
            
            var minLatitude = document.getElementById("minLatInput").innerHTML;
            var maxLatitude = document.getElementById("maxLatInput").innerHTML;
            var minLongitude = document.getElementById("minLongInput").innerHTML;
            var maxLongitude = document.getElementById("maxLongInput").innerHTML;
            
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "php_mysql_table_result.php",
                async: false,
                data: {"minLatitude": minLatitude,
                    "maxLatitude": maxLatitude,
                    "minLongitude": minLongitude,
                    "maxLongitude": maxLongitude
                },
                success: function(data) {                    
                    document.getElementById("ajaxresults").innerHTML = data;
                },
                error: "ERROR"
            })

            }
        
    </script>

<p>
    Results: <br></p>
    <div id="ajaxresults">Results Here</div>


</html>
```

PHP Code:

```php
<?php

// Include Config File
require_once "config.php";
  
// SQL query 
$sql = "SELECT registration_number, entity_name, latitude, longitude, structure_type, height_of_structure, status_code
    FROM database
    WHERE latitude >= :minlatitude AND  
    latitude <= :maxlatitude AND
    longitude >= :minlongitude AND
    longitude <= :maxlongitude;";

  
$sth = $conn->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindValue(':minlatitude', $minlatitude, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':maxlatitude', $maxlatitude, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':minlongitude', $minlongitude, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':maxlongitude', $maxlongitude, PDO::PARAM_STR);

# Try query or error
$sth->execute();
if (!$sth) {
    echo 'An SQL error occured.\n';
    exit;
}

$data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo "<table>
    <th>Registration Number</th>
    <th>Entity Name</th>
    <th>Latitude</th>
    <th>Longitude</th>
    <th>Structure Type</th>
    <th>Structure Height (ft)</th>
    <th>Status Code</th>";

foreach($data as $row) { 
    echo "<tr>
        <td>" . $row['registration_number'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['entity_name'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['latitude'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['longitude'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['structure_type'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['height_of_structure'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['status_code'] . "</td>
        </tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

?>
```

Current Results of the Ajax:

> = :minlatitude AND latitude <= :maxlatitude AND longitude >= :minlongitude AND longitude <= :maxlongitude;"; $sth = $conn->prepare($sql); $sth->bindValue(':minlatitude', $minlatitude, PDO::PARAM_STR); $sth->bindValue(':maxlatitude', $maxlatitude, PDO::PARAM_STR); $sth->bindValue(':minlongitude', $minlongitude, PDO::PARAM_STR); $sth->bindValue(':maxlongitude', $maxlongitude, PDO::PARAM_STR); # Try query or error $sth->execute(); if (!$sth) { echo 'An SQL error occured.\n'; exit; } $data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); echo ""; foreach($data as $row) { echo ""; } echo "
> Registration Number Entity Name Latitude    Longitude   Structure Type  Structure Height (ft)   Status Code
> " . $row['registration_number'] . " " . $row['entity_name'] . " " . $row['latitude'] . "    " . $row['longitude'] . "   " . $row['structure_type'] . "  " . $row['height_of_structure'] . " " . $row['status_code'] . "
> "; ?>

Comment: This suggests you are not serving the page from a webserver which is capable of executing php. Have you installed anything like Apache or IIS which could do this?

Comment: I'm using the PHP Server extension in VS Code and my local drive for now while I learn. I'm able to run the PHP file on a standalone basis, which works, and I've been able to handle other tasks such as using PHP to upload data to MySQL though a HTML form. I know this is not a permanent solution though so maybe I should switch over to a proper webserver? Thanks

Comment: First of all: 
What happens when you call that php Site in your browser?
Where did you convert the $_GET['minlatitude'] variable to $minlatitude?

I would recommend a JSON to transfere Datas between two pages.

Comment: I've tested the PHP by setting $minlatitude (and other parameters) to a static '30' for example and it runs fine in my browser (call this static version). When I run the same static PHP through an Ajax I get the same incorrect result I included in my post, so I think the problem is beyond the data transfer. Also I previously had a '$minlatitude = $_GET['minLatitude']' in my dynamic PHP version (which attempts to pass the data) and also didn't fix it. I'm thinking it may be a server issue based on the first comment above. Thank you for the JSON suggestion I'll look into that.

Comment: does *config.php* start with *<?php* tag?

Comment: Yes config does start with that and works in my other PHP files, thanks

Comment: It would generally be more reliable to install something like xampp and use the php file through that, yes

Comment: It seems that around *require_once "config.php"* the web server stops interpreting PHP and uses `>` of `WHERE latitude >= :minlatitude` as a closing delimiter for a tag "opened" somewhere in the code above .
Is the Ajax result exhaustive or could there be hidden tags before it?

Comment: I've switched over to xampp and code is working now. There must have been a limitation with ajax for the php server I was using. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ajax does not limit php. More likely you opened the html file a different way, without the php server, or perhaps on a different port, and therefore when the ajax request was made it was treated as a basic request and didn't trigger the php engine. Glad you solved it though.